# Inverse Laplace of $\frac{s}{(s+3)^{5}}$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Struggling to answer this transform. Anyone able to give me a walkthrough?

I know that the inverse transform of $$\frac{1}{(s+a)^{n}}$$ is $$\frac{1}{(s+a){!}}{t}^{n-1} {e}^{-at}$$

But I am unsure how to get to that position as I have "s" instead of a number. I assume I can use partial fractions but with it being to the power five I feel like that would be difficult and length to solve, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: You must know that the inverse transform of $\dfrac{1}{(s+a)^{n}}$ is 
$$\frac{1}{(n-1){!}}{t}^{n-1} {e}^{-at}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write $\frac {s}{(s+3)^5}$ as  $$\frac {s+3-3}{(s+3)^5} = \frac {s+3}{(s+3)^5} -\frac {3}{(s+3)^5}$$

$$=  \frac {1}{(s+3)^4} -\frac {3}{(s+3)^5}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, it's all clear to me now. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding.